# go install errors out with mkdir: permission denied

Tags: go

Even after ensuring proper read / write access to your `GOPATH` folder you can still receive permission errors.

I tried `sudo chmod -R sourcefolder/` and `sudo chown -R username sourcefolder/` without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to unset my `GOBIN` variable in order to fix this issue. `GOBIN` doesn't need to be set anymore by default. More details here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InstallTroubleshooting

You can check whether it's set with `echo $GOBIN`. You can unset it via `unset GOBIN`. If it's set in your `bash` file then it's different per operating system:

macOS: `nano ~/.bash_profile`
Linux: `nano ~/.bash_aliases`

Use `CTRL+W` on either platform to search and type in `GOBIN`.